# Get value of a key from a dictionary array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

so in Javascript I have an array structured like this:

```
car = [{id: "1", brand: "Opel"}, {id: "2", brand: "Haima"},{id: "3", brand: "Toyota"}]
```

How can I get the values of all the brands only.

Comment: `car.map(item => item.brand)`

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it.

1. A simple solution if you just want to log it to console

        car.forEach(car => console.log(car.brand));

Iterate over your car object with forEach.
2. If you want to collect it in an array for further manipulation

        const brands = car.map(car => car.brand);

Map returns a new array of brand in that case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should help:

```js
const car = [{id: "1", brand: "Opel"}, {id: "2", brand: "Haima"},{id: "3", brand: "Toyota"}];

const brands = car.map(({ brand }) => brand);
```

Comment: you could also write car.map( o => o.brand) to save some letters

Answer (score 6):

You can use array map to return all brands. Look at the following use of map.

```
car.map(o => o.brand)
```